# What is the best way to clear floated elements in CSS?

Tags: page-layout, css

What is currently considered the best way to clear CSS floated elements that will:

- Keep the HTML markup as semantic and free of unnecessary elements as possible, and
- Be a cross-browser, cross-platform solution that works reliably for the majority of browsers?

Comment: should be moved to Stack Overflow

Comment: Are all CSS questions better suited to SO than Design.SE or just ones that are more technical in nature than design related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a graphic design question. It's a CSS one, so belongs on StackOverflow.

That said, the answer for keeping the HTML clean is simply to give the parent an overflow. So if your markup is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div style="float: left;"></div>
    <div style="float: left;"></div>
</div>
```

you can give wrapper an overflow:

```
.wrapper {overflow: auto}
```

And now `.wrapper` will contain both the floats.

That's usually all that is needed.

Sometimes, in older IEs, the container also needs a width.

Comment: Thanks. This method seems to be the favoured solution from other research I've done since posting the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this more complicated, but a simple way is to add a class to your CSS called .clearfix with this attribute:

```
.clearfix {clear: both;}
```

Then just insert a  tag underneath what you want to clear.

Google clearfix for more modern ways to define the tag.

Comment: Sorry, the tag didn't format and show correctly. Put this as the next div: <div class="clearfix"></div>

Comment: @DA. is correct, the additional (likely semantically unnecessary) markup from the clearfix solution violates my first criterion. A valid answer, but I'd like to see if anyone proposes a solution that doesn't require additional markup.

Comment: My reasoning behind doing it this way:
It is a compromise because it isn't semantic. But it works cross-browser and backwards without jumping through any hoops.
I understand the distaste for it, though.

Answer (score 0):

a little tricky, but it's work for modern browser :)

```
.wrapper::after {
    content:"";
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best method I've seen for this is using :before & :after pseudo elements for modern browsers and zoom: 1 for older versions of IE.

```
/* For modern browsers */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear:both;
}

/* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
.cf {
    zoom:1;
}
```

More info here:
http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/